# Start FirebaseMessagingService through API

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can I start or restart `FirebaseMessagingService` from my code. The reason I need this is that the Service is always closed randomly.

Comment: The `FirebaseMessagingService` automatically starts when the app is first started. It does not auto-close. Can you share details of when it closes? Is there an error that is logged? Maybe even a stack trance?

Comment: When i close my app the serive is still alive but when the app is killed because low memory or when the display is off i don´t receive any messages more

Comment: If the system kills a service due to low-memory constraints, there isn't anything you can do about it (as far as I know). Restarting the service would mean that you re-introduce the low-memory condition.

Comment: it is still not working :(

Answer (score -1):

FirebaseMessagingService doesn't need to be active for your app to receive the notifications.

The service is executed only to process incoming messages or token requests.

Don't worry if the service is stopped. Android will restart it when a new notification arrives.

Comment: No , that is the point ! When i leave my mobile a day alone and try to send a mmesage to my mobile , nothing happens :C

Comment: If that happens then it's a bug in the version of Android produced by the manufacturer of the device. Please try it on a different device.

Comment: then the bug is on all devices (s7 , s3 , oneplus 2 , s5) ?

Comment: it is still not working ... When i wake up and try to send a message to my handy , it took more then a half hour that i receive the message ;(

Comment: This may probably happen due to doze mode and other battery saver restrictions.